# Executing "[]" in bash gives a weird error message.. why?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

An ordinary command not found error says:

`bash: sadfasdf: command not found...`

However, if executing `[]` in bash, it gives two error messages instead of one:

`bash: []: command not found...
Failed to search for file: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._pk_5ftransaction_5ferror.Code14: Invalid input passed to daemon: char '[' in text!`

What does the second error message mean, and how does `[]` cause the error to happen?

Comment: I've never seen anything like that.  Do you have something strange pre-parsing your command lines or parsing program output?

Comment: If I type just `[]` at my bash prompt, the behavior varies from one system to another. On one system I just get `bash: []: command not found`; on another (with a slightly newer bash), I get `bash: no match: []`. Remember that `[abc]` is a wildcard matching a single character `a`, `b`, or `c`. It's not clear what `[]` should match. An effective workaround would be: *Don't Do That*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the same problem described [here](http://markmail.org/thread/wje6bqhdntmcr6we#query%3a+page:1+mid%3apc2car2eu4przycx+state%3aresults) on the PackageKit mailing list. If you're using PackageKit, that's likely your problem.

More generally, you should check whatever seems to be running through the BASH `command_not_found_handle` function.

From `man bash` :

> "If the search is unsuccessful, the shell searches for a defined shell function named
>   command_not_found_handle. If that function exists, it is invoked with the original 
>   command and the original command's arguments as its arguments, and the function's 
>   exit status becomes the exit status of the shell."

Simply, it's a function which is called whenever BASH can't find the command you entered.

Seems likely something is defining that function, and doesn't like square brackets!

`grep` around your `/etc/profile` and bash config files, it'll be there somewhere :)